# CPR and Previous day High/Low line - Only for current day

Tags: pine-script-v5

I tried google to find a solution, but couldn't.
I don't have any coding knowledge and pine script is super new to me. There was couple of similar questions, but still no solution. I tried to figure this out on my own, but couldn't. I tried it for a week. There are pieces here and there, but couldn't put them together and make it work.

Need to draw line(s) for CPR and previous day high and low. I neither want those lines to be drawn for all the past days nor extending to the unforseeable future. I just need them for today, when market opens I want them - CPR (calculated based on previous day's data), and previous day's high/low line.

I want the space between top and bottom CPR to be filled with some colours. Using plot() limit the kind of line styles, I prefer either dashed or dotted. Looks like I have to use line() function.

Built-in pivot has codes where we can specify how many days it needs to be drawn, I thought I could figure out looking into the source code, but that's too complex for me.

How do I draw the line from today's first bar to last bar at the very start of the session/trading day?

Market hours: 0900hrs to 1600hrs
Time frame: 1min, 5min, 15min, 30min and 60min.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head for some more hours and tried to piece the things together and got this. It's almost I was looking for. Most of this code is by someone else, don't remember the name or from where I got the code, could be here or reditt or pinescript community, documentation or google and some add/remove/edit from my side.

I didn't add pivot line here, just the top and bottom of the CPR and shaded.

Why was I saying it's 'almost' what I was looking for?
Because the starting point of the lines are not exactly where I wanted them to be, it should be first bar of the new session instead of last bar of previous session. I tried, but as of now I couldn't find how to start from where it should. Other than that, it's perfect.

I didn't understand the code most of it. So I won't be able to answer anything technical here.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Test', overlay=false)

pivot = (high + low + close) / 3
tcpr = (high + low) / 2
bcpr = pivot - tcpr + pivot

//Edit # 2
//PrevBars = input(title='Show previous highs and lows?', defval=false)
//condition = not(timeframe.isweekly or timeframe.ismonthly)

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
cprtop = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', tcpr, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
cprbot = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', bcpr, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Edit # 2
//plotshape(series=condition and PrevBars ? h[1] : na, title='Previous high', color=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.absolute, editable=true)
//plotshape(series=condition and PrevBars ? l[1] : na, title='Previous low', color=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.absolute, editable=true)
//plotshape(series=condition and PrevBars ? cprtop[1] : na, title='CPR Top', color=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.absolute, editable=true)
//plotshape(series=condition and PrevBars ? cprbot[1] : na, title='CPR Bottom', color=color.new(color.black, 0), location=location.absolute, editable=true)

// Draw lines from the previous highs and lows
newSession = ta.change(time('D'))
count = ta.barssince(newSession)

var line PrevHigh = na
var line PrevLow = na
var line CTop = na
var line CBot = na

if newSession
    PrevHigh := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=h[1], x2=bar_index, y2=h[1], color=color.black, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    PrevLow := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=l[1], x2=bar_index, y2=l[1], color=color.black, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)
    CTop := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=cprtop[1], x2=bar_index, y2=cprtop[1], color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    CBot := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=cprbot[1], x2=bar_index, y2=cprbot[1], color=color.black, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)
    line.delete(id=PrevHigh[1])
    line.delete(id=PrevLow[1])
    line.delete(id=CTop[1])
    line.delete(id=CBot[1])

if not barstate.islast
    line.set_x2(id=PrevHigh, x=bar_index)
    line.set_x2(id=PrevLow, x=bar_index)
    line.set_x2(id=CTop, x=bar_index)
    line.set_x2(id=CBot, x=bar_index)
else
// Before Edit # 1
//    line.set_xloc(id=PrevHigh, x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
//    line.set_xloc(id=PrevLow, x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
//    line.set_xloc(id=CTop, x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
//    line.set_xloc(id=CBot, x1=time[count + 1], x2=time_close, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

//Edit # 1
    line.set_xloc(id=PrevHigh, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=PrevLow, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=CTop, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=CBot, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

linefill.new(CTop,CBot,color.rgb(151,151,151,80))
```

**Edit # 1**
The code above keeps drawing those lines in live market, which I didn't want and didn't know until when I checked it online today. And figured out how to correct that and also how to start the line from the first bar of the current session instead of previous day's last bar.

```
    line.set_xloc(id=PrevHigh, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=PrevLow, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=CTop, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
    line.set_xloc(id=CBot, x1=time[count], x2=time[count] + 1 * 86400000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

**Edit # 2**
Looks like some of the codes are not actually been used for the said purpose, so you can remove them if it's alright with you.